# Setting custom request header using SolrJ

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have a custom http filter configured in Solr which is invoked first (executes before org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter) for each request that hits solr. The custom filter looks for a particular request header in all the incoming solr requests,and only if its present, it sends it down for further processing by solr.

I use SolrJ for certain queries. Is there any way I can set a HTTP request header when querying Solr thru SolrJ?

My Solr and SorlJ version is 5.4.0

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `HttpSolrClient` creating your own class `MyHttpSolrClient` and customise the behaviour of `executeMethod` adding your custom request headers.

```
public class MyHttpSolrClient extends HttpSolrClient {

  public MyHttpSolrClient(String baseURL) {
    super(baseURL);
  }

  public MyHttpSolrClient(String baseURL, HttpClient client) {
    super(baseURL, client);
  }

  public MyHttpSolrClient(String baseURL, HttpClient client, ResponseParser parser) {
    super(baseURL, client, parser);
  }

  protected NamedList<Object> executeMethod(HttpRequestBase method, final ResponseParser processor) throws SolrServerException {

    // **Here you add your custom header**
    method.addHeader("Name", "Value");

    return super.executeMethod(method, processor);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts on this solution?

```
// somewhere in my client initialization code
HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = (HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) -> {
        request.addHeader("myheadername", "myheadervalue");
};

HttpClientUtil.addRequestInterceptor(interceptor);
HttpSolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(serverUrl).build();
```

The question/concern I have has to do with this comment in `HttpClientUtil` (https://solr.apache.org/docs/8_8_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.html)

> This relies on the internal HttpClient implementation and is subject
> to change.

> WARNING: This API is experimental and might change in
> incompatible ways in the next release.

I also have a question/concern about any lingering effects to any subsequent client instances that I create. Will those instances also get configured with the same interceptor? Is there something I can do to ensure they won't?